# setEnable Button after validation with 2 TextWatchers

Tags: android, validation, textview

after validating six EditTexts with two different TextWatchers (one for names and one for numbers) I want to enable my "Fertig" Button. Therefore I added some variables [...]Valid to check if all conditions are fulfilled. Do I have to change the position of the if query?

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView nachricht;
    private Button weiterFertig;
    private EditText vorname;
    private EditText nachname;
    private EditText strasse;
    private EditText nummer;
    private EditText plz;
    private EditText stadt;
    private boolean ersterKlick;
    public boolean vnameValid;
    public boolean nnameValid;
    public boolean strasseValid;
    public boolean stadtValid;
    public boolean nummerValid;
    public boolean plzValid;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nachricht = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nachricht);
        weiterFertig = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weiter_Fertig);

        vorname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vorname);
        nachname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nachname);
        strasse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.strasse);
        nummer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nummer);
        plz = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plz);
        stadt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stadt);

        ersterKlick = true;
        vnameValid = false;
        nnameValid = false;
        strasseValid = false;
        stadtValid = false;
        nummerValid = false;
        plzValid = false;

        nachricht.setText(R.string.willkommen);
        weiterFertig.setText(R.string.weiter);
        weiterFertig.setEnabled(false);

        weiterFertig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (ersterKlick) {
                    nachricht.setText(getString(R.string.hallo, vorname.getText(), nachname.getText(), strasse.getText(), nummer.getText(), plz.getText(), stadt.getText()));

                    vorname.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    nachname.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    strasse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    nummer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    plz.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    stadt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    weiterFertig.setText(R.string.fertig);
                    ersterKlick = false;
                } else {
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });

        /*
         * Validator1
         */
        TextWatcher numberChecker = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence number, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence number, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable number) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2,}");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(number);

                if (number.hashCode() == nummer.getText().hashCode()){
                    if (m.find()){
                        nummerValid = true;
                    } else{
                        nummerValid = false;
                    }
                }

                if (number.hashCode() == plz.getText().hashCode()){
                    if (m.find()){
                        plzValid = true;
                    } else{
                        plzValid = false;
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        /*
         * Validator2
         */

        TextWatcher inputChecker = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence input, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence input, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable input) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß ]{3,}$");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

                if (input.hashCode() == vorname.getText().hashCode()) {
                    if (m.find()) {
                        vnameValid = true;
                    } else {
                        vnameValid = false;
                    }
                }

                if (input.hashCode() == nachname.getText().hashCode()) {
                    if (m.find()) {
                        nnameValid = true;
                    } else {
                        nnameValid = false;
                    }
                }

                if (input.hashCode() == strasse.getText().hashCode()) {
                    if (m.find()) {
                        strasseValid = true;
                    } else {
                        strasseValid = false;
                    }
                }

                if (input.hashCode() == stadt.getText().hashCode()) {
                    if (m.find()) {
                        stadtValid = true;
                    } else {
                        stadtValid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        };


        vorname.addTextChangedListener(inputChecker);
        nachname.addTextChangedListener(inputChecker);
        strasse.addTextChangedListener(inputChecker);
        stadt.addTextChangedListener(inputChecker);

        nummer.addTextChangedListener(numberChecker);
        plz.addTextChangedListener(numberChecker);

        if (vnameValid && nnameValid && strasseValid && stadtValid && nummerValid && plzValid) {
            weiterFertig.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            weiterFertig.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move that condition to another function, and call it inside both validators. When the events are fired, they call to your validators and will check the conditions that change the button.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should check for enable or disable button inside TextWatcher

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  .....
    TextWatcher numberChecker = new TextWatcher() {
        Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence number, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @
        Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence number, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @
        Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable number) {
            ...
            checkEnableOrDisable();
        }
    };
    TextWatcher inputChecker = new TextWatcher() {
        Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence number, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @
        Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence number, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @
        Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable number) {
            ...
            checkEnableOrDisable();
        }
    };
    .....
}



public void checkEnableOrDisable() {
    if (vnameValid && nnameValid && strasseValid && stadtValid && nummerValid && plzValid) {
        weiterFertig.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        weiterFertig.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Hope this help